# In the given figure, $PC$ is the angle...

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $PC$ is the angle bisector of $\angle APB$ then prove that $XY||AB$

[image]

My attempt

$$\angle APC=\angle BPC$$
$$\angle APC=\angle AQC$$
$$\angle XPB=\angle XQY$$
$P,X,Y$ and $Q$ are Concyclic.

Please help me to complete from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that $P,X,Y$ and $Q$ are concyclic.

Then, we have
$$\angle{PYX}=\angle{PQX}=\angle{PQA}=\angle{PBA}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT.- The point $Q$ may vary throughout the arc $\widehat{APB}$ of the circumference  and the angle $\angle {AQC}$ remains constant and equal to the half of $\angle{APB}$ i.e. equal to $\angle CPB$ (Note that in particular can be $ Q = B $ in which case you have an obvious "parallelism").

Can you deduce in the figure below the equality of angles $\angle PYX=\angle PBA$? Why this is sufficient to conclude the proof?

[image]